# Final list or array wont store the value

Tags: java, android, arrays, list

```
public class from_the_database {

    public String last_entry(String object) {

        DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final String ok = object;
        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // array to save result
        Query query = database.child("records").orderByChild("object").equalTo(object);

        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot post : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Data_model_milk dmm = 
                        post.getValue(Data_model_milk.class);
                        Log.e("value",dmm.getDate()); // this works though
                        list.add("item was added last at " + dmm.getDate()); // not being added
                    }
                } else {
                    list.add("no insert for " + ok); // not being added
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e("from the db cancelled", databaseError.toString());
            }

        });

        Log.e(object, list.get(0)); // not available
        return list.get(0); // list.get(0) is empty
    }
}
```

So the problems are
 dmm.getDate() is returning a value, but it is not being saved in the array list or any other variable which needs to be returned by the main function last_entry

I have used final arrays intitalized with size 0,1 and 10 still nothing seems to work.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Your code is incomplete. You are **only** defining a listener, but you add to your query *after* you ran it? Is that how it is support to work? The listener itself doesnt get active unless "something" triggers it. Adding a listener to something shouldnt trigger anything. So the part that causes events to be sent ... seems to be missing here?

Comment: code inside event handler is not executed because no corresponding event has occurred

Comment: it is because when i add Log.e("value",dmm.getDate()); // this works though i get the desired output but when i try to save it to a variable in this case the ArrayList it doesnt save.. i am sure it has to do with scope of variable .. the function is being called though and is executed

Comment: @AdarshaNepal show us what u mean. Add the `Log.e` to your code

Comment: Log.e is like println for android and i use log.e to get the value in my console it woks well.. i get the desried output.. but i cant manage to get the variable to return.. it gives array index out of bounds exception

Comment: @AdarshaNepal I know. But add it to your code show us what's not working

Comment: it has already been updated in the lastest edit.. its inside the for each loop right above of list.add ... now the thing that is not working is.. i cant seem to get the value returned from dmm.getDate() to the main function's return

Comment: what is the output of `dmm.getDate()`

Comment: @AmmarAli date in string format the datatype is string too

Comment: show me the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you are doing, not going to work. I guess you are trying to make your class as a utility class.

You should change the approach, may be below code can help

```
public class from_the_database {

    public void last_entry(String object, OnDataChangeCallback listener) {

        DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final String ok = object;
        Query query = database.child("records").orderByChild("object").equalTo(object);

        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot post : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Data_model_milk dmm = 
                        post.getValue(Data_model_milk.class);
                        Log.e("value",dmm.getDate()); // this works though
                        listener.onDataChange("item was added last at " + dmm.getDate());
                    }
                } else {
                    listener.onDataChange("no insert for " + ok);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e("from the db cancelled", databaseError.toString());
            }

        });
    }

    public interface OnDataChangeCallback{
        void onDataChange(String data);
    }
}
```

Now call last_entry method like below

```
last_entry("queryString", new OnDataChangeCallback(){
    public void onDataChange(String data){
      // do something with data
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The scenario which is occuring in your code can only happen when same object-name exists in both base-class and inner-class

```
public class LockTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ArrayList<String> strList = new ArrayList<>(); // Same object name variable in base-class and inner-class
    Hello hello = new Hello() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            strList.add("Hello");
        }
    };
    System.out.println(strList.size()); // Output is 0
  } 
}

interface Hello {
ArrayList<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
void run();
}
```

This seems unlikely in your case, but have a look at your issue from this angel. Maybe this is the case

Answer (score 0):

`onDataChange` is `asynchronous` so your

```
Log.e(object, list.get(0)); // not available
return list.get(0); // list.get(0) is empty
```

will be executed before `onDataChange` is called because of this your list is always empty.

So instead of returning a string from your function its better to create a new function with string parameter and call that function inside your `onDataChange` like this:

```
public void last_entry(String object) {

    DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    final String ok = object;
    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // array to save result
    Query query = database.child("records").orderByChild("object").equalTo(object);

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot post : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Data_model_milk dmm =
                            post.getValue(Data_model_milk.class);
                    Log.e("value",dmm.getDate()); // this works though
                    list.add("item was added last at " + dmm.getDate()); // not being added
                }
            } else {
                list.add("no insert for " + ok); // not being added
            }

            performSomeAction(list.get(0));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("from the db cancelled", databaseError.toString());
        }

    });
}

public void performSomeAction(String msg){
    //Do your action here
}
```